# Изменение стилей при помощи js без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript

```js
function bgimg_off() {
  var bg = document.getElementById('background');
  bg.classList.remove("on");
}
```

```css
#background.on {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../img/Montenegro.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="on" id="background">
  <div class="trash" onclick="bgimg_off()">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/trash.png" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

При нажатии на div.trash вызывается функция при которой у div#background удаляется класс "on" в следствии чего фон ,по идее, исчезает. Это работает, но вот только при выполнении функции страница перезагружается и соответственно фон появляется снова. Никто не знает как выполнить функцию без перезагрузки страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let someFunctionToHideBackground = e => {
  e.preventDefault(); // отменяет действие браузера по умолчанию.
  background.classList.remove("on");
};

document.getElementById("clickable").addEventListener("click", someFunctionToHideBackground)
```

```css
#background.on {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mK72EwuxZAU/hqdefault.jpg) 0 no-repeat;
}

img {
  height: 30%;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="on" id="background">
  <div class="trash">
    <a href="#" id="clickable">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-qj4O2aHQqc/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```